# Java interface for textfields

Tags: java

So i have textfields and i need to create the interface for them.

I have KeyListener for textfield1 that allows to input only integer value into textfield, but i need to make the interface for each textfield that i have

```
textfield1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                  char c = e.getKeyChar();
                  if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
                     (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
                     (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                    getToolkit().beep();
                    e.consume();
                  }
                }
              });
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're facing? Store the listener in a variable and pass this variable to all the `addKeyListener` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store your `KeyAdapter` in a variable, then pass the variable around?

```
KeyAdapter adapter = new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
              char c = e.getKeyChar();
              if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
                 (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
                 (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                getToolkit().beep();
                e.consume();
              }
            }
          };

someTextField.addKeyListener(adapter);
someOtherTextField.addKeyListener(adapter);
```

Or, if you are lazy enough that you don't want to write `addKeyListener` multiple times,

```
Stream.of(textField1, textField2, textField3).forEach(x -> x.addKeyListener(adapter));
```

Comment: @Forfenix do you think my answer answers your question please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!